# My node based coffee script not running (Error %1 is not a valid application.)

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, socket.io

I am working with this repository https://github.com/indiejoseph/Radar
When I run the coffee script located in the web folder of repositor.

It gives a following error:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwjNIlr7qO3_YTltQzRhNkdmX2M/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, this looks like it might be related to 32/64 bit issues of the node dependencies, see [here](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/2136) and [here](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/2926) for some similar issues.

Just running through the list of some obvious things:

- reinstall all the dependencies: delete `node_modules` folder, `npm cache clear` and `npm install`.
- Have you installed the [arduino drivers](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/windows#toc4)?

Which version of node do you have installed?

Comment: Node Version: v0.10.36

Comment: And I cleared cache and deleted node_modules and then did npm install and it worked.... Thanks alot for the help... :)